# JQuery Validate Issue when using bootstrap col-xs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

JQuery Validate Issue when using bootstrap

I use jquery validate and below is my code

```
      errorElement: 'div',
        errorClass: 'has-error',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
         error
            .css('background-color', '#000000')
          error.insertAfter(element.parent('div'));
        },
        highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
          $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
          $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]")
            .addClass(errorClass);
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
 $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
          $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]")
            .removeClass(errorClass);
        }
```

The problem with the code above is because

if i use normal div like this

```
<div class="input text required"><label for="my_pay">Basic Pay</label>
<input id="my_pay" name="my_pay" maxlength="64" type="text" />
</div>
```

Its works fine, the validate message appear below.

But when I use

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-xs-4"><div class="input text required">
    <input id="name" name="name" maxlength="64" type="text" />
</div></div>

<div class="col-xs-4"><div class="input text required">
    <input id="weight" name="weight" maxlength="64" type="text" />
</div></div>

</div>
```

The validation will appear at the right side of the col-xs-6 text field and the original text field will be push down and the layout will be distorted.

Such as example

```
[      Text Field      ] [      Text Field      ]
```

If validate it will become

```
[      Text Field      ] validate message
 [      Text Field      ] validate message
```

What I want is  the validate message appear below of the 2 text fields that is bootstrap

```
[      Text Field      ] [      Text Field      ] 
Validate Message
Validate Message
```

Problem is my code also need to works for normal div that is not bootstrap.

The field that I have for bootstrap is name and weight

**THANKS FOR HELPING!!**

Comment: In browser console inspect live html and css rules that apply to error element and adjust accordingly. Why can't you use default error placement?

Comment: You need to provide enough code to construct a working demo... not just the little pieces. After all, we don't even know what your CSS is doing to all this.  I mean, you're asking us to figure out why your layout is being broken but we don't even know anything about how your CSS is affecting the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relevant code...

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.css('background-color', '#000000')
    error.insertAfter(element.parent('div'));
},
```

1. REMOVE `error.css('background-color', '#000000')` entirely.  You should not be messing with CSS from inside the `errorPlacement` function.  It doesn't even make any sense to be doing this with jQuery when you can just specify this rule with CSS in the first place.
2. `error.insertAfter(element.parent('div'))` is putting your error message element *outside* of the `div` that contains your `input` element.  I'm unclear about what you really want, but based on what you've shown, simply using the default `errorPlacement` function would put the message element *inside* the container and immediately after each `input` element.  Since your error message is a `div`, it should already appear on a new line under each `input`.  In other words, remove the `errorPlacement` option entirely and see what happens.  However, we have absolutely no idea how your CSS is affecting all this.

Otherwise, you're going to have to inspect the live DOM using your browser tools to see where the plugin is inserting the message and what the CSS is doing.  Then if not correct, figure out exactly where it needs to be... then adjust the CSS and/or HTML accordingly.  Fix the dynamic HTML by adjusting the code within `errorPlacement`.